# window is bigger than it's only layout. How to make it wrap_content?

Tags: android, layout, height, android-constraintlayout

I have a window in an Android app which does not size correctly. The goal is to make the window wrap it's content (the `TextView`-s and the two `Button`-s), so it's a window in the middle of the screen, but it's height remains the whole screen despite my every attempt.

**Image**: [image: the floating window, with the wrong height]
As you can see from the code, blue is the background of the included layout, black is the background of the main layout (for debug purposes).

**Code/layout:**
  *XML of the activity:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/NotificationLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000FF0"

    tools:context="com.tenderportkft.sped_ex.DialogActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/NotificationDetails"
        layout="@layout/auction_listitem_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/NotificationNoButton"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NotificationNoButton"
        android:onClick="OkButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/AuctionPopup_NotInterestedText"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NotificationDetails"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NotificationYesButton"
        android:onClick="OkButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/AuctionPopup_OpenAuctionText"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NotificationNoButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*XML of the included layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TopRowText"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BottomRowText"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TopRowText"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*XML of the style of the window:*

```
<style name="DialogActivityTheme" 
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>         
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**Research:** Researching this problem proved to be very hard as every single search result was either about problems with `RelativeLayout`-s or cases where the content is bigger than the window, not the other way. So my research mostly consisted of after not findig anything on google and here, randomly modifying height-settings of the layouts (and the style), so most combinations that seem logical are tried out and tested.

**Platform**: Android 6.0.1, API 23

EDIT: I know that floating windows are a discouraged way of displaying content, but I'm not responsible for the design, only the implementation.

EDIT2: Got closer to locating the problem - the included layout is the cause, and the solution is to replicate the contents that layout in my floating window instead of simply including the whole layout. Whether it's because of the fact of including or the specifics of the included layout is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
<style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black_20</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
            <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        </style>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    // place components here 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```